# old.house.wiring

Tags: electrical

ok so my primary positioning in life has been mechanicing and in greater hours more specifically heavy equiptment and semis.  Although I have extensive experience building race cars and motorcross and dragrace off and on road race engines. In the.most recent few years i somehow landed back in rental house rennovations and maintainance for a.while.  Ive done a.substantial amount of.plumbing and electrical work usually daily for.over 3 years.  So obviously im comfortable.with ac and dc power and even have a great understanding of ac production changed to dc.in basically any dc sourced self.charging system.   So crudentials aside im baffled and confused with a problem at my own house of all places.  I oversee 300 mostly older houses by luck of the.draw.ive gotta wave the.white flag at home.  My house is around 100 yrs old.or.getting fairly close.  Ive rewired.quite a few.areas.just for.sheer convenience b/c of a lack of outlets and lights such as.no hallway lights.and hardly any basement lights.  I promise im not an idiot and have worked on stuff all the way up to 3 phase motors and permited high volgage resdential.power.  Im.just emphasising i didnt goof up.  I understand electricity in great depth.  I wire 90% of everything live and know how to test or rewire 110 220  660  whatever.  Still at my house a 100 amp modern breaker was installed prior.to me living here and they installed conduit and gfi's in bathroom and kitchen and such but they failed.to separate anything.  I typically run 14/2 15 A for lights and normal.outlets and 12/2 20A in baths and kitchens and install gfi,s around any water sources.  so in my house they didnt run separate circuits to the baths or kitchen or anywhere.  My house is 3 levels.  Basement,1st, and 2nd floor.  Ok so every light and outlet on every level all lead back to 1 15 A breaker at the panel on all 12/2 ancient wire.  In my attempts to separate.things i located 2 main junction areas and by the time  i scaled them down from multiples lmao its all.still.1.freakn wire can kill everything but things like the furnace.  it gets more interesting.  One.of the junction.areas.was.what proved to be the old breaker panel in a wood cabinet in the kitchen.  So the.most interesting event has been when i separated.2.neutrals in the basement    should.i repeat       PULLED.APART TWO.NEUTRALS TIED TOGETHER   and it charged a large part of my hoise 220 temporarily.  My icemaker was shooting flames out of the dispenser while frying the.computer board and a surge protector failed.and i lost an lcd television.  Damn any educated tips minus the i wish i couldve seen that would.be much appreciated.  The story sounds funny unless its yours so   HEEEEELLLLLPPPP     before i bulldoze this piece of fine wired nightmare on elm.street.   Im out of ideas next to running new circuits everywhere.  Which i added 7 breakers and started some.of that already but the majority of the.house is still wired in some weird series.or.parallel series that i cant figure out.  please help

Comment: Maybe break it up into paragraphs?

Comment: You could get rid of 95% of that text glob you wrote and get right to the question.

Comment: WHY THE HELL are you doing anything live??? And WHY IN THE WORLD would you separate a neutral splice live?? IMO you think you really know what you are doing but this seems like the classic case of knowing just enough to be dangerous.

Comment: Sloooowly step away from the wiring and hire a competent electrician.

Answer (score 2):

You separated a neutral splice that was the neutral for a multi-wire branch circuit (shared neutral) while it was live. That's what happens when you do that. Both legs of the circuit then try to find a neutral to return current on so they try to use each other. Some parts of the circuit can see 0 voltage while others can see the full 240V.